# php: find an url image in specific div

Tags: php, html, regex, image

I have this piece of code:

```
if (!$thumbdone) {
    if (intval($fb_image_use_content)==1) {
        $imgreg = '/<img .*src=["\']([^ ^"^\']*)["\']/';
        preg_match_all($imgreg, trim($post->post_content), $matches);
        if (isset($matches[1][0])) {
            //There's an image on the content
            $image=$matches[1][0];
            $pos = strpos($image, site_url());
            if ($pos === false) {
                if (stristr($image, 'http://') || stristr($image, 'https://')) {
                    //Complete URL - offsite
                    $fb_image=$image;
                } else {
                    $fb_image=site_url().$image;
                }
            } else {
                //Complete URL - onsite
                $fb_image=$image;
            }
            $thumbdone=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Find the first image within a code.
The problem is I want to find the first image inside a div structured in this way:

```
<div style="display:block" class="ogimage">
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-1030 size-full" src="http:/site.com/image.jpg" alt="image" width="600" height="315">
</div>
```

I Googled this: 
https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20get%20image%20from%20div

I also tried with http://www.phpliveregex.com/

but nothing. Help?

Comment: Whats your expected output? To extract the complete image tag or just the `src` of the image inside the div tag?

Comment: Search for PHP Xpath. You could get the first image source like this: `//img[1]/@src` or `//div[@class="ogimage"]/img[1]/@src`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the right [**tool**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for the job instead of trying to parse HTML using a regular expression.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$img   = $xpath->query('//div[@class="ogimage"]/img');

echo $img->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/169190)

Comment: Tnx for help, but i need regex :( no way?

Comment: Why do you need regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` like this:

```
$html = '<div style="display:block" class="ogimage"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-1030 size-full" src="http:/site.com/image.jpg" alt="image" width="600" height="315"></div>';
$result = explode($html)[7];
```

Comment: hi, the div is in a complex page. I need to edit the first code. This is a part of wordpress plugin.